# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/PBEParametersGenerator

Tags: java

I am working with sevenzipjbinding api and  crypto api and when i run the class i have this :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/bouncycastle/crypto/PBEParametersGenerator

Comment: Sounds like a problem for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the jars after downloading the package from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html and put them in your classpath.